# Nodejs Mysql optimizing query

Tags: mysql, node.js, performance, left-join

I am using `mysql2` module in nodejs v8.9.4.
This is my function to get a message from message queue which meets this conditions :

`status==0`
if count of `botId` with `status==1` is less than 10
if `retry_after` in `wait` table for `botId+chatId` and just `botId` is less than `NOW`(timestamp)
if there is no same `chatId` with `status==1`

```
  static async Find(activeMessageIds, maxActiveMsgPerBot) {

    let params                 = [maxActiveMsgPerBot];
    let filterActiveMessageIds = ' ';
    let time                   = Util.GetTimeStamp();

    if (activeMessageIds && activeMessageIds.length) {
      filterActiveMessageIds = 'q.id NOT IN (?) AND ';
      params.push(activeMessageIds);
    }

    let q =
          `select q.* 
            from bot_message_queue q 
            left join bot_message_queue_wait w on q.botId=w.botId AND q.chatId=w.chatId 
            left join bot_message_queue_wait w2 on q.botId=w2.botId AND w2.chatId=0 
            where
              q.status=0 AND
              q.botId NOT IN (select q2.botId from bot_message_queue q2 where q2.status=1 group by q2.botId HAVING COUNT(q2.botId)>?) AND 
              ${filterActiveMessageIds} 
              q.chatId NOT IN (select q3.chatId from bot_message_queue q3 where q3.status=1 group by q3.chatId) AND 
              (w.retry_after IS NULL OR w.retry_after <= ?) AND 
              (w2.retry_after IS NULL OR w2.retry_after <= ?)  
            order by q.priority DESC,q.id ASC  
            limit 1;`;

    params.push(time);
    params.push(time);

    let con    = await DB.connection();
    let result = await DB.query(q, params, con);
    if (result && result.length) {
      result      = result[0];
      let updateQ = `update bot_message_queue set status=1 where id=?;`;
      await DB.query(updateQ, [result.id], con);
    } else
      result = null;

    con.release();
    return result;
  }
```

This query runs fine on my local dev system. It also runs fine in servers phpmyadmin in couple of milliseconds.

BUT when it runs throw nodejs+mysql2 The cpu usage goes up to 100%
There is only 2K rows in this table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bot_message_queue` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `botId` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `chatId` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `message` longtext NOT NULL,
  `add_date` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0=waiting,1=sendig,2=sent,3=error',
  `priority` tinyint(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '5' COMMENT '5=normal messages,<5 = bulk messages',
  `delay_after` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '1000',
  `send_date` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `botId` (`botId`,`status`),
  KEY `botId_2` (`botId`,`chatId`,`status`,`priority`),
  KEY `chatId` (`chatId`,`status`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bot_message_queue_wait` (
  `botId` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `chatId` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `retry_after` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`botId`,`chatId`),
  KEY `retry_after` (`retry_after`),
  KEY `botId` (`botId`,`chatId`,`retry_after`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

UPDATE: [Real table data here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=10gkrTA-csKSJuSQ7ymXwQ8Fxz08FZj1Y)
UPDATE 2:
FetchMessageTime :
- Min : 1788 ms
- Max : 44285 ms
- Average : 20185.4 ms

The max was like 20ms until yesterday :( now its 40 seconds!!!

UPDATE 3: I merged these 2 joins and wheres:

```
left join bot_message_queue_wait w on q.botId=w.botId AND q.chatId=w.chatId 
left join bot_message_queue_wait w2 on q.botId=w2.botId AND w2.chatId=0 

(w.retry_after IS NULL OR w.retry_after <= ?) AND 
(w2.retry_after IS NULL OR w2.retry_after <= ?)
```

into a single one, I hope this will work as intended!

```
left join bot_message_queue_wait w on q.botId=w.botId AND ( q.chatId=w.chatId OR w.chatId=0 )
```

and for the time being I removed the 2 wheres and the query time went back to normal.

```
q.botId NOT IN (select ...)
q.chatId NOT IN (select ...)
```

So these 2 where queries are the chock points and needs to be fixed.

Comment: It would be much easier to help, if this `DDL` had some test data.

Comment: @JitendraSoftgrid https://drive.google.com/open?id=10gkrTA-csKSJuSQ7ymXwQ8Fxz08FZj1Y

Answer (score 0):

`NOT IN ( SELECT ... )` is difficult to optimize.

`OR` cannot be optimized.

In `ORDER BY`, mixing `DESC` and `ASC` eliminates use of an index (until 8.0).  Consider changing `ASC` to `DESC`.  After that, `INDEX(priority, id)` *might* help.

What is `${filterActiveMessageIds}`?

The `GROUP BY` is not needed in

```
 NOT IN ( SELECT  q3.chatId
            from  bot_message_queue q3
            where  q3.status=1
            group by  q3.chatId )
```

`INDEX(status, chatid)` *in this order* would benefit that subquery.

`INDEX(status, botid)` *in this order*

More on index creation:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Answer (score 0):

1. I would replace the NOT IN subquery with a NOT EXISTS in this case, as it can perform better.
2. Switch the ORDER BY to either all DESC or all ASC

So to optimize the query, first, add these indexes:

```
ALTER TABLE `bot_message_queue` ADD INDEX `bot_message_queue_idx_status_botid_chatid_priori_id` (`status`,`botId`,`chatId`,`priority`,`id`);
ALTER TABLE `bot_message_queue` ADD INDEX `bot_message_queue_idx_priority_id` (`priority`,`id`);
ALTER TABLE `bot_message_queue` ADD INDEX `bot_message_queue_idx_botid_status` (`botId`,`status`);
ALTER TABLE `bot_message_queue` ADD INDEX `bot_message_queue_idx_chatid_status` (`chatId`,`status`);
ALTER TABLE `bot_message_queue_wait` ADD INDEX `bot_message_queue_wa_idx_chatid_botid` (`chatId`,`botId`);
```

Now, you can try to run this query (please note I changed the order by to all DESC, so you can change it to ASC if that's a requirement):

```
SELECT
        bot_message_queue.* 
    FROM
        bot_message_queue q 
    LEFT JOIN
        bot_message_queue_wait w 
            ON q.botId = w.botId 
            AND q.chatId = w.chatId 
    LEFT JOIN
        bot_message_queue_wait w2 
            ON q.botId = w2.botId 
            AND w2.chatId = 0 
    WHERE
        q.status = 0 
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT
                1 
            FROM
                bot_message_queue AS q21 
            WHERE
                q21.status = 1 
                AND q.botId = q21.botId 
            GROUP BY
                q21.botId 
            HAVING
                COUNT(q21.botId) > ? 
            ORDER BY
                NULL
        ) 
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT
                1 
            FROM
                bot_message_queue AS q32 
            WHERE
                q32.status = 1 
                AND q.chatId = q32.chatId 
            GROUP BY
                q32.chatId 
            ORDER BY
                NULL
        ) 
        AND (
            w.retry_after IS NULL 
            OR w.retry_after <= ?
        ) 
        AND (
            w2.retry_after IS NULL 
            OR w2.retry_after <= ?
        ) 
    ORDER BY
        q.priority DESC,
        q.id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: can't use `Inner Join` because not all the rows in T1 have a matching row in T2, `Inner Join` will ignore those rows but That's not what I want

Comment: @Exlord, sorry about that, didn't notice those conditions at first glance. I modified both indexing and query recommendations. Please give it another try and provide feedback.

Comment: I need the oldest entries first so `q.id DESC` doesn't work it have to be `ASC`. Ans the `NOT EXIST` subqueries won't work for me either because the subquery is meant to filter the main query based on its returned values, it can't be a simple `true/false`

Comment: @Exlord, feel free to change it to ASC. Regarding the NOT EXISTS parts - that alternative is equivalent to the NOT IN statements in the original query, as I added the relevant correlated conditions inside the subqueries. Why wouldn't that work? Doesn't the query return the same results?